# Wordpress Post loop with query $args on search.php results?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a search results page and I'm trying to exclude specific post formats. I found this query but I don't know how make the post loop works, I don't even know the code. And, I don't know how to put the 404 error not found on the search.php.

This is the code

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => 'post-format-quote', 'post-format-video',
      'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    )
  )
);
query_posts( $args );
?>
```

I first tried something and worked fine, but if i set "4 post per-page" it counts all the formats post, and if the standard posts on the search results should have been 3 and 1 quote-format post, it shows 3 standard post and an empty space.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php if( get_post_format() == 'quote' ) : ?>
<?php elseif( get_post_format() == 'link' ) : ?>
<?php elseif( get_post_format() == 'video' ) : ?>
<?php elseif( get_post_format() == 'image' ) : ?>
<?php else : ?>


post

<?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: maybe because you don't do anything when the post format is quote ? please post the whole code and not part of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the whole code of my search.php. This was the only way to not display other formats post on my search results. I just want the loop to not count "other formats post" on my results. I want to show 4 results per-page and has to be 4 standard posts format.

```
  <?php

get_header(); ?>

<div id="content" class="site-content">


<div id="news-page">


<div class="right">


<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
<div class="left">

<div class="newstitle">RISULTATI</div>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php if( get_post_format() == 'quote' ) : ?>
<?php elseif( get_post_format() == 'link' ) : ?>
<?php elseif( get_post_format() == 'video' ) : ?>
<?php elseif( get_post_format() == 'image' ) : ?>
<?php else : ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Leggi">

<div class="post"> 

<div class="data">
<span class="giorno"><?php the_time('j M Y') ?></span> <span class="commenti"><?php comments_number('0 commenti', '1 commento', '% commenti'); ?></span>
</div>

<div class="thumb"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'news-page' ); } ?></div>
<div class="thumb-full"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'news-page-full' ); } ?></div>

<div class="title"><?php echo get_the_title( $post_id ); ?></div>

<div class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>

<div class="diss"></div>


<div style="position: absolute; z-index:999; bottom: 0; left: 0; font: normal 10px arial; padding: 3px;"> In <?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->cat_name . ' '; } ?></div>


</div>

</a>



<?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>


    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: wheres your `query_posts()` function call ?